# Extract a string from long text to be used as a search key

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a list with many variable product descriptions:

**SHeet1**

[image]

And I need to give a rating for each description.
As a parameter for consultation I have only the model that makes up each description, with the respective classification:

**Sheet 2**

[image]

How can I search and sort the descriptions?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I would like to extract the model from the description to be able to use it as a search key in a `Vlookup`, for example. Follow the link: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jt1Htw0bePVxFkZUOlXj8kBehtEH-35c-ZrhLgjwJ0s/edit#gid=0] @player0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; 
 FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A; Sheet2!A2:A<>"...")))); Sheet2!A2:B; 2; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

### FIX:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; 
 SORT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A; Sheet2!A2:A<>"");
 "+"; "\+"); "("; "\("); ")"; "\)"); 1; 0)))); Sheet2!A2:B; 2; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, @player0. Applying to my real model the result was empty. I gave you a spreadsheet with a simulated situation. I updated with my real data now: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jt1Htw0bePVxFkZUOlXj8kBehtEH-35c-ZrhLgjwJ0s/edit#gid=0]

Comment: @LucasGóes answer and your sheet updated (plus sign and parenthesis needs to be escaped in regex)